# Modal in Ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

How to open a modal dialog box on click of a button in ag-grid react. This modal box in my case is a react component. So basically, i have to call a component as a modal dialog box on button click using ag-grid.

isPopUp does not suffice.

Answer (score 0):

ag-grid does provide various events like (cell-click, row-click, double-click etc.) if you can bind function and use one of those events to open modal.